# Center a caption under an image in bootstrap column

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, caption

I'm using CSS to size and center images in bootstrap col-md-4's and everything is centering ok except the actual caption container. I used text-align which centered the text but can't figure out how to align the entire caption center. Do I need to figure out the pixels and margin-left it? Thanks for any help, I'm sure it's easy! http://http://codepen.io/chiggory/pen/xOZXQB

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 border"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive size" src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/lightning.jpg"></a>

<div class="caption">Test</div>
     </div>
 </div>

.size {
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border:5px solid #800000;
}

 .caption {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #800000;
    width: 230px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap `center-block` class..

```
<div class="caption center-block">Test</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/UD1wOD7iLW

Answer (score 3):

Some times what you would need is Bootstrap `text-center` class:

```
<div class="caption text-center">Text here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to the caption like you have on the image.

```css
.size {
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border:5px solid #800000;
}

 .caption {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #800000;
    width: 230px;
   
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 border"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive      size" src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/lightning.jpg"></a>

<div class="caption">Test</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

To make them both the same size you need to either add the same border that's on the image to the caption, or add `box-sizing: border-box` to the image.

Comment: That makes sense, just wasn't thinking of them the same way for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Center a caption under an image in bootstrap column

versi minify

```css
.size{height:auto;width:100%;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border:5px solid maroon;box-sizing:border-box}.caption{font-size:20px;color:#fff;background-color:maroon;width:100%;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);text-align:center}.display-container{position:relative;height:230px;width:230px;//float:left;//display:block}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 border display-container"> <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive size" src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/lightning.jpg" /> </a><div class="caption center-block">Test</div></div></div></div>
```